# Issue with PHP DateTime's date property

Tags: php, datetime

I have a curious problem.

The following code generates an error.

```
$startDate = new DateTime();
//  print_r($startDate);
$i = strpos($startDate->date,' ');
$this->startByTime = substr($startDate->date,0,$i).'T'.substr($startDate->date,$i+1).'.000Z';

Notice: Undefined property: DateTime::$date in C:\xampp\htdocs\hpace\buildschedule.php on line..
```

And the date property seems to be undefined. as `$this->strartByTime = 'T000Z'` at the end of all this.

Now if I uncomment the print_r statement all works fine. Can anyone explain this to me.?

Comment: I suggest that, if it isn't listed as a property in [the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) then it isn't an accessible property.

Comment: What are u trying to do?

Comment: @best... I was actually just using DateTime for the first time and was using print_r to see what it was offering up. Then when I got rid of the print_r the error occurred.  I then got really curios about his there and gone property. I am using format now get the date.

Answer (score 3):

There is no `->date` attribute in the [DateTime object](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), which is why PHP's complaining about `$startDate->date`.

Perhaps you mean `$startDate->format('r')` or similar?

Comment: Interesting Marc. Why I wonder does this work with the print_r statement shich does show a date property. DateTime Object ( [date] => 2013-04-09 21:34:09 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Berlin ) What would print_r be doing that would cause the property to appear.