# Laravel + DateTime : date property isn't defined?

Tags: php, laravel, datetime

This will work well (meaning I can work on `$today->date` here without issues) :

```
$today = new \DateTime('NOW');
$today->format('Ymd');
var_dump($today);
$date = date('Ymd', strtotime($today->date . ' +1 Weekday'));
```

But this raises an error :

```
$today = new \DateTime('NOW');
$today->format('Ymd');
var_dump($today);
$date = date('Ymd', strtotime($today->date . ' +1 Weekday'));
```

The error being :

```
Undefined property: DateTime::$date
```

This is strange ! It seems that `$today` (DateTime object) will work as an object, or at least its `date` property will exists, **only if it is being called (in a `var_dump` here...) once before.**

What am I doing wrong ?

---

*Note* : I've been doing my homework, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15910329/3489447) tells that there is no `->date` property in a [DateTime object](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php).

But `$today->date` being working in my example and `var_dump` being returning this :

```
object(DateTime)#493 (3) { 
   ["date"]=> string(26) "2016-12-09 11:51:00.000000"
   ["timezone_type"]=> int(3)
   ["timezone"]=> string(3) "UTC"
}
```

Of course, using `date` as an array key will not work neither :

```
Cannot use object of type DateTime as array
```

---

*Note* : Not answering the question but if needed by someone having the issue, one can have the string value of the DateTime object this way (format of your own) :

```
$today = new \DateTime('NOW');
$date = $today->modify('+1 Weekday')->format('Ymd');
```

Comment: Thanks for giving it a try RiggisFolly. I've just tried in phpfiddle.org which is using PHP5.6.18 and it works. I'm using PHP 7.0.12 and Laravel's php artisan server. This might be a Laravel issue...

Comment: The `var_dump()` and `print_r()` (tried that to), must be activating an undocumented method inn DateTime to allow those functions to work. The side effect of running `var_dump()` must create these extra properties.

Comment: Use `$date = date('Ymd', strtotime($today->format('Y-m-d') . ' +1 Weekday'));` instead

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel there's a standard of using Carbon class for handling date-time manipulations. It's a wrapper around standard PHP DateTime object but enchanced with a lot's of usefull methods http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/
So you can get Now like

```
$now=Carbon::now();
$now->addDay(); // or
$now->addDays(1);  // to add one or whatever days to current
```

Note modifiers on Carbon object like addDays(1) will change original object, so if you need to left it untouched for some puprose just clone it first

```
$another_date=clone($now); 
$another_date->addDays(1); // $now still untouched
```

to format is as a string use

```
 $now->format('Y m d');
```

or

```
 $now->toDateString();                          // 2016-12-10
 $now->toFormattedDateString();                 // Dec 10, 2016
```

Formatting is the same as for DateTime in PHP.